# While creating new project I am getting error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have just started to use silverlight in visual studio 2k8. I have installed silverlight 3 tools for visual studio 2K8. Now while creating a new project an error is thrown - "object reference is not set to an instance of an object". Screen-shots are attached. Could you guyz please help?

[Error screen shot](http://img412.imageshack.us/i/silverlight2.jpg/)
  [Create project screen shot](http://img42.imageshack.us/i/silverlight.jpg/)

Comment: Do you have any call stack information or the code on which it's failing?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the tools?

Comment: Yes i have tried reinstalling.

Where can I get the call stack information? While creating project it is throwing error.

Comment: have you install silvelight runtime environment.. sometime this cause reason of such problem.. try to get this and install on your machine..

Comment: @Andrew anything in the Event Logs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try re-setting your Visual Studio settings. Go to Start > Visual Studio Command Prompt (2008) and run the commands sequentially:

```
devenv /ResetSettings
devenv /ResetSkipPKGS
```

See if this does the trick...

Comment: I had seen similar reset suggestions on MS forums and tried them without result.  However I tried yours anyway, still no joy "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I also previously tried reinstalling Silverlight.  VS2010 SP1

Comment: I remember this came up for me when dealing with a different symptom, but just in case it helps, have you tried running VS as an administrator? (And/or the above commands?)

Comment: Also fixed VS2015 for me today! Note that the parameters seem to be case sensitive!!

Comment: I tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/22871532/3952692 but command prompt says `'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed VS2008 SP1 before installing Silverlight 3 tools?

I would recommend you to uninstall Silverlight 3 tools first and then look at the Instructions in the below MSDN download link and install Silverlight 3 tools following these instructions:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9394

==================================================================

Ready reference for Installation Instructions:

Before installing Silverlight 3 Tools:

Upgrade Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 to Service Pack 1 and make sure that the Visual Web Developer feature is installed.
or
Install Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express with SP1.
Uninstall any Beta or Preview versions of Expression Blend

Note: This release will not work with the Visual Studio 2008 RTM or Visual Studio 2008 SP1 BETA.

===================================================================

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once and I just did a complete repair of VS.  Have you tried that?  Not an uninstall/reinstall, but a repair?

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and now solved it............

Follow the given path and shift+delete everything.

**Windows XP:**

C:\Documents and Settings\your_user_name\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache

C:\Documents and Settings\your_user_name\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache

**Windows 7:**

C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache

C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache

C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

So the solution is "***TO CLEAR THE CACHE OF YOUR SYSTEM***"

Comment: Helped in Win8.1 and VS 2013, path is C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache. After VS restart - it asked to remove some shapes from diagram (classes that were deleted from project) and opened Ok, without reseting all VS settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with Windows 8, VS2012 Pro and WP8 SDK.

Try to either update or remove NuGet.

My Solution: **UNINSTALLED** NuGet (as updates to it did not work)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with **Visual Studio 2017**. When I disable my **ReSharper** from **Tools > Extensions and Updates**, then this message is disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I too had similar issue faced in my VS 2015, Windows 10 OS.

Solution : Close the VS IDE and Open it again.

Hope it should be resolution.