# Visual Studio 2008 Design View not working?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I download visual web developer 2008 to develop seilver-light apps BUT I faced problem!
Why design view not appear in visual studio web developer 2008 :( !! just xaml window appears !!

I tried by **repair and re-install** it also I see some solutions which not obvious! as:

- [Visual Studio 2008 Hangs in Design View with ASP.Net web pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2010/03/29/visual-studio-2008-hangs-in-design-view-with-asp-net-web-page.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2008 - html not updating with design view](http://forums.asp.net/t/1380268.aspx?Visual%20Studio%202008%20html%20not%20updating%20with%20design%20view)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture/image of the issue?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38b8guvbY-UbHVDMTNhU1NocGM/view?usp=sharing @EBrown

Comment: Can you right click on the file in the solution explorer, select "Open with..." and choose "XAML UI Designer"?

Comment: I don't have this chose just I have (XML Editor, XML Editor with Encoding) :( how can I add this choice?   @DavidG

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Visual Studio had failed to load one or more packages in the past. To reset:

1. Quit Visual Studio
2. Run `devenv /resetskippkgs` from a [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Source: Accepted answer on [No xaml designer in vs2008](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/053dc5c3-27fe-4ea2-a7f5-5c6cf35000bb/no-xaml-designer-in-vs2008?forum=vswpfdesigner)

For anyone else on Windows 8.1 having trouble finding the Visual Studio Command Prompt, check out [Where is Developer Command Prompt for VS2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476588/where-is-developer-command-prompt-for-vs2013)

Comment: Find the [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and run it. Type the command and hit enter.

Comment: this command not fund in such folder for visual web developer 2008!!

Comment: I run it via VWDExpress.exe/resetskippkgs BUT also it does not work the same problem :((((((((((((((((((((((((((((