# Visual Studio 2015 Command Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I've never used the command window in Visual Studio but now I'm researching how to use build scripts.  I was following this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx

And I got to the part that said to type in the following in the Command Window:

```
msbuild buildapp.csproj /t:HelloWorld
```

So that is what I typed in but I got

> msbuild is not valid

Is there another command I need to type in before entering msbuild?

I was able to go to the MSBuild.exe location on my C: drive using the DOS cmd window.  I was able to run it there.  If that is the answer, then fine.  I guess I was thinking it would be able to run it from the Visual Studio Command Window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run it in the Visual Studio Command Prompt, not in the Command Window in Visual Studio. Notice the note under the "Building the Target" section.

See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/237894/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-command-prompt-into-the-visual-studio-ide) to embed the Command Prompt inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Now that I know what window works, that comment makes total sense.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

I think that you might be using the *wrong* command window (The one in Visual Studio available by going to View -> Other Windows -> Command Window).

The one you should be using the is the "[Developer Command Prompt For VS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx)" available as a shortcut in the Start Menu.

[image: Developer Command Prompt For VS2015 screenshot]

Comment: Is there anyway to include that prompt inside of Visual Studio itself?  Thanks for the answer.  I've never used this feature before so this is brand new to me.

Comment: @webdad3 I answer that in another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31102479/162671) on SO but Tomer's link works too.

Answer (score 0):

I have rarely used the command window much in visual studio either. It is however used for debugging, not for building visual studio projects.